# setTimeout blocking issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, conways-game-of-life

I'm writing a "Game of Life" in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).  I have all the logic done in a function called `doGeneration()`.  I can repeatedly call this from the console and everything goes as planned, however, if I put it in a `while` loop the execution blocks the UI and I just see the end result (eventually).

```
while (existence) {
    doGeneration();
}
```

If I add a `setTimeout()`, even with a generation limit of say 15, the browser actually crashes (Canary, Chrome).

```
while (existence) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        doGeneration();
    },100);
}
```

How can I call `doGeneration()` once every second or so without blocking the DOM/UI?

Comment: Is your while loop getting hit more than once? If the setTimeout is getting called more than once you'll actually create more instances of doGeneration. Also keep in mind setTimeout uses milliseconds as opposed to regular seconds

Comment: if you want to call a function to execute over and over with a set time in between executions, you should use setInterval instead of setTimeout in a loop. [Check it out here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want setInterval

```
 var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
     doGeneration();
 }, 1000);

 // call this to stop it
 clearInterval(intervalId);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `requestAnimationFrame(doGeneration)`. The idea of this function is to let the browser decide at what interval the game logic or animation is executed. This comes with potential benefits.

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `setINterval` or `setTimeout` and assume some random time interval will be enough for the `UI` to update you shoul/could make the `doGeneration` smart enough to call itself after dom was updated and if the condition of `existence` is satisfied.